# VSC Apex Replay Debugger - Run through multiple classes?

Tags: apex, visualstudiocode, apex-replay-debugger

Having an issue where the Apex Replay debugger doesn't go through all the code in a debug log and once it steps into a class referenced from another class it exits out once it gets to the end of the referenced class.

With the proper trigger set up of one trigger / one handler class / one action class, its impossible to debug the after triggers as it runs through the beforeTrigger, goes into the action class and then exits out, even though the before log clearly shows an afterTrigger was run.

Any ideas on how the replay debugger should work in order to replay all the code in a debug log? i've watched all the Youtube videos i could find but they were all one class

Comment: Are all of the classes you want to step through part of your SFDX project? Do the classes you have match what is in the org that you obtained the log from? (differences in line numbers can throw off the replay debugger quite easily)

Comment: Definitely part of the SFDX project. And yeah classes match, log is a pull from the Sandbox i've been working in